# Need JPA query syntax to fetch all of an entity's list property values

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot 3 / Spring Data JPA / JDK19 project in which my entity has a list of Strings:

```
public class Recipe {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private List<String> tags;
  ...
```

My repository extends **MongoRepository<Recipe, String>** (a CrudRepository).
I need to return the set of all tags.

I've tried **findAllTags(), findByTagsContaining(String tags)** passing in "", "*", " ", "?", "%", "%%" and "%?%" and the same with **findByTagsLike(String tags)** with no success. I could fetch all recipes and parse over their tags lists but I thought Spring Data JPA query creation might handle it better. Yesterday I wrote a repository method as findByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrBodyContainingIgnoreCaseOrTagsContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByNameAsc

This can't be that hard ;) Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't have any annotations on `private List<String> tags;`, never seemed to need it. I'm wondering though if my model is too simple. Maybe it needs to be `@OneToMany private List<Tag> tags;` where Tag is another entity with its own repository? Then I could query that repository with `findAll()` or `findDistinct()` or something. It would make the current search a pain though.

Comment: I don't seem to have access to the `@OneToMany` annotation. I'm on Java19 and I think the `javax.*` packages have been removed if it came from there. Does that mean it's no longer needed?

Comment: take a look here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.aggregation and try to see if some modification of case 9 might work for your case